# Handling Nested Property Values

Tags: c#

What is the elegant solution to access nested property values?

**Example:** 
In some cases it could look as follows:

```
public void someFunction()
{
    this.Device.ResponseHandler.Process(this.Device.TcpClient.responseMessage, this.Device.TcpClient.responseType)
}
```

My solution was to copy objects, just to shorten the names afterwards.

```
public void someFuntion()
{
    // Just for shorten the access name afterwards
    ResponseHandler responseHandler = this.Device.RepsonseHandler;
    TcpClient tcpClient = this.Device.TcpClient;

    responseHandler.Process(tcpClient.responseMessage, tcpClient.responseType);
}
```

Comment: So your question is towards best practises, or are there deeper concerns, like for example older style eventhandlers where an eventhandler could theoretically have been removed after you check if it was null or not?

Comment: Just best practises, no deeper concerns.

Comment: But then it is offtopic Joko, as it's opinion based, at least primarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mostly opinion based, but there are generally two ways:

1. The one you are using.
2. List every argument in new line:

   ```
   public void someFunction()
   {
       this.Device.ResponseHandler.Process(
           this.Device.TcpClient.responseMessage,
           this.Device.TcpClient.responseType
       );
   }
   ```

IMO both are equally readable and in second approach you don't need another variables :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a usings at the top if you don't like long names:

```
using ResponseHandler = this.Device.ResponseHandler;
using TcpClient = this.Device.TcpClient;

public void someFunction()
{
    ResponseHandler.Process(TcpClient.responseMessage, TcpClient.responseType);
}
```